# SKLearn/Tabluar Data: How to handle DataFrame elements that contain lists other than one hot encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, tabular

Summary: I am trying to predict categorical aspects of a court case (e.g. outcomes) using sklearn's `RandomForestClassifier` on a data set thats approx 1000 rows x 20 columns. I know that the plaintiffs attorneys are an important factor in this, and in this type of case it is common to have 2 or 3 plaintiffs attorneys under one law firm and 2 or 3 under another law firm on the same case.

I have a column in a DataFrame with a list of attorneys on a case. There are ~1000 rows and ~200 unique attorney names. One way to handle this would be to one hot encode the attorney names with `pd.get_dummies()` This leads to over-fitting or really poor models (R^2:0.2)

Any ideas on a better solution given my relative small size of a data set? Maybe only use get_dummies if they appear more than n times in the data set? Any way to use my lists other than one hot encoding?

For example:

```
index   attorney_name
0       [A1,A2,A3]
1       [A2]
2       [A6]
3       [A2,A19]
…       …
1004    [A200,A201]
1005    [A202]
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but do you pass your data to `pd.get_dummies()` as list?. So say [A1, A2] becomes one binary attribute and [A1] another?

Comment: No but conceivably I could one hot encode these lists such that there’s a sparse set of 200+ columns

Comment: No, no, I meant you should not do it but rather have a separate column for each individual attorney id. But if you already broke up the lists then that's fine. Besides this, however, the model performance really depends on your data. By the way, have you tried posting this to http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I have not tried posting there, I'll hopefully have mroe data to add soon. I think I will try OHE the attorney IDs that appear more than [n] number of times, and see if maybe breaking out the more frequent ones matters. (i.e. has a feature importance worthwhile and a model that generalizes better]

Comment: Yes, if I understand well, this is I was trying to suggest..